# How to create an alias with fixed/static parameters in Powershell

Tags: powershell, alias

I want to create an alias with fixed (static) parameters,
like the example below:

```
set-alias -name xxx -value Get-Process -ComputerName group1\xpto-pc
```

I don't want to changeable parameter values...
I want them to be fixed in the alias...

- note: i do not want to create a function

Comment: I believe this isn't possible with an Alias but certainly is with a Function. Why do you explicitly not want a Function?

Comment: It's not, you _will_ have to define a function (or equivalent) for this

Comment: I already have this working with functions... If it work with alias (since parameters are static) it would have a nice advantage to one of my projects of modeling/prototyping a language in powershell... by the way... I asked this question because I find so stupid that fixed parameters aren't accepted in an alias (basically a string to be replaced) that I thought I was making some moron mistake... it appears not....

Comment: Take a look at some of the built-in wrapped functions like `mkdir`. `Get-Command mkdir | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition`

Comment: by the way... picking the replace string path I referred above... even dynamic parameters would be easy (and light) to implement in alias... this is a tipical Microsoft failure...

Comment: thanks for the tip Ben...

Comment: As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Aliases?view=powershell-3.0) aliases can be defined for *"a cmdlet or for a command element, such as a function, script, file, or executable file"*. They cannot be defined for (partial) commandlines.